# Mapping coordinates to item not working as expected

Tags: qt, mapping, qml, coordinate

I am having problems getting coordinate mapping to work as intended. For some reason the result is usually off, unless a very specific condition is met.

Here is an example scenario:

[image]

Objects are ordered in a tree, with each node being 100 pixels square. Mapping is done from each node to the parent of the first node. Items are paranted as they are ordered, e.g. 1 is parent of 2 and 4, 2 is parent of 3 and so on...

- Node0 is at local coordinates 0,0 in its parent, so logically, mapping the position of node 0 returns 0,0
- Node1 however does not return 100, 100, instead it returns 200, 200
- Node2 and 3 behave differently, this time the values are correctly incremented from the previous (incorrect) node value to 300, 300 and 400, 400 respectively
- Node4 returns 300, 700 even though it it is only 100 pixels below node 2
- Node5 - 200, 1000
- Node6 - 300, 700 - it is lower than node 5 but shows a lower y value
- Node7 - 200, 1400 - 100 pixel lower than node 6 returns 700 additional pixels y value

It seems like this mapping doesn't do what I assume it does, which is produce a coordinate, absolute to the object being mapped to, e.g. the top left corner of Node 0. Which should produce the expected values:

- Node0 0, 0
- Node1 100, 100
- Node2 200, 200
- Node3 300, 300
- Node4 200, 400
- Node5 100, 500
- Node6 200, 600
- Node7 100, 700

It seems that every new child at a given level skews the result off. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: This likely results from mapping the items own coordinates relative to its parent as like they were relative to the item. Instead you should map the item's coordinates from inside the item i.e. (0, 0) to get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating the `mapToItem` method I concluded it is not the right tool for the job, so I wrote my own.

```
QPointF absolutePosition() {
        QPointF p(0, 0);
        QQuickItem * item = this;
        while (item != Object::_rootUI) { // absolute position relative to _rootUI
            p += item->position();
            item = item->parentItem();
        }
        return p;
    }
```